# Remove The ScrollBar in the WebView Javafx

Tags: java, webview, webkit, scrollbar, javafx

How to remove the scrollbar automatically in the WebView of Javafx ?

When you click "Cadastre" will open a screen, this screen is in javascript and is unconfigured because of the scrollbar, so we wanted to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Normally for a [`ScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html) you would do something like this:

```
scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
```

However, the scrollbars inside WebView are not your JavaFX UI control, but a part of the displayed webpage. Thus, you control them with CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

You can save this as a .css and apply it as a user stylesheet, similarly [user style sheets in normal browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Sources), using this code:

```
webView.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation("path/to/style.css");
```

If the user stylesheet you created is a part of your project's resources then you should externalize it so:

```
webView.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(getClass().getResource("/path/to/style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: I'm actually creating a browser and every time I opening screens in javascript the scrollbars appear and desconfiguram the screens.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by opening screens in javascript, you should describe your problem more clearly in your original question

Comment: When you click "Cadastre" will open a screen, this screen is in javascript and is unconfigured because of the scrollbar, so we wanted to remove it

Comment: I cant make out anything from the picture or your comments, have you tried applying the user stylesheet to the webview as described?

Comment: This code will remove the scrollbars of any page loaded in the WebView once it is loaded (even when following links to other pages): `engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>()
 {

  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> o, State old, final State state)
  {
   if (state == State.SUCCEEDED)
   {
    System.out.println("Page loaded: " + engine.getLocation());
    engine.executeScript("document.style.overflow = 'hidden';");
   }
  }

 });`

Comment: how can disable mouse scroll for webview by this way with css ?