# JavaFX Webview scrollbar redraw issues

Tags: netbeans, webview, javafx

I am using JavaFX Webview to display some web content in my Swing application. Webview displays the pages well, except it has a small bug where the Webview scrollbar area is not redrawn correctly upon resize. See image.

[image: See the ghosting effects behind the scrollbar]

This happens occasionally if I resize the owner JFXPanel. I am using the de-facto SwingInterops demo from [NetBeansTutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-javafx.html). Is this a known issue? If so, is there a way to work around it?

Thanks

... Alan

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found a working solution using a CSS file for the Webview.

```
final WebView webview = ...;

File f = new File("$SOME_PATH\custom.css");
try {
    webview.getEngine().setUserStyleSheetLocation(f.toURI().toURL().toString());
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    // not important here
}
```

Where the Custom.css file has this content,

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 16px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track  {
    background-color: white;
}
```

As suggested on [Remove The ScrollBar in the WebView Javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498287/remove-the-scrollbar-in-the-webview-javafx), I thought overflow-x/y properties are sufficient by themselves to hide the scrollbar, but it doesn't work unless the webkit-scrollbar properties are also present. I don't understand the solution, but it eliminates the drawing issue.

I am using JavaFX 2.2, JDK 7u21 x64 on Win7.