# Pannable WebView in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview, scrollpane, panning

Does anybody have an idea how to make the WebView pannable in JavaFX? I know, that WebView is a child of the ScrollPane in JavaFX, and it is possible to make a ScrollPane pannable easily. But I have no idea how to make it pannable with a simple WebView.

If you have any ideas, please let me know. Maybe with Javascript, but how? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you exactly mean with `pannable`?

Comment: That instead of the normal ScrollPane, you can scroll the WebView by mouse clicked. Like in Google Maps for Example

Comment: so you mean like dragging with `mouse clicked`?

Comment: yes exactly !:)

Comment: to remove the scrollbar see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498287/remove-the-scrollbar-in-the-webview-javafx). to enable drag scroll is a javascript thing. if you want i can provide an complete answer :)

Comment: that would be awesome ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a site srollable by mouse dragging is a html thing so first remove the scrollbar from the `<body>` by adding following css to the site:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

(if you don't know how to add css to a webview [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783532/applying-css-file-to-javafx-webview))

Then to enable the scrolling by dragging it you must use javascript. ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743228/scroll-the-page-on-drag-with-jquery/19743358) this question but it uses jquery).

**OR**

you can use this library ([link](https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll)) i found.

then add this to the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/asvd/dragscroll/master/dragscroll.js" />
```

**and**

also add a class named `dragscroll` to whatever you want to make scrollable by drag (in your case `<body>`).

(if you have trouble with adding elements or attributes i can recommend you [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) as html parser)

Comment: webview.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
webview.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER); is not possible with WebView. Just give the WebView a class in CSS and remove the ScrollBars. But with you're solutions mentioned in the answer it works fine ! :)

Comment: @SGE59 i thought it had these policies(it  was described like this in another older question). I will edit the question :)